# Subclass Method Return Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

I'm trying to allow the enduser to filter their data and then provide output based on the selected *Report* instance and date range.  My *Report* hierarchy is setup using Entity Framework (TPH). Currently, I've setup an abstract method on the base class that will return type *ReportResult*:

```
 public abstract ReportResult GetContent(IQueryable<Employee> employees, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
```

Since each *Report's* *ReportResult* is completely different than the other I've created an empty *ReportResult* class (abstract) and each report instance will return their own *ReportResult*.  This doesn't feel like the correct way to do something like this, but since I cannot use generics with Entity Framework I'm not too sure what to do. Is using the empty abstract base class for *ReportResult* okay for the return value of GetContent or is there a better way to do this?

**Example**

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract ReportResult GetContent(IQueryable<Employee> employee, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public override ReportResult GetContent(IQueryable<Employee> employees, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        FooResult fooResult;
        // Transform/Filter the employee IQueryable
        return fooResult;
    }
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    public override ReportResult GetContent(IQueryable<Employee> employees, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        BarResult barResult;
        // Transform/Filter the employee IQueryable
        return barResult;
    }
}

public abstract class ReportResult
{   
    // Hierarchy will hold transformations on the employee IQueryable.  This
    // could be a filtered subset of employees and/or aggregates performed to
    // obtain an overview.
}

public class FooResult : ReportResult
{
    public string FooSpecificProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string FooSpecificProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class BarResult : ReportResult
{
    public int BarProperty1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime BarProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I'm sorry, is there any concern with me using an empty base class just so I can return the FooResult / BarResult? What would be an alternative way to do something like this?

Comment: Without knowing what you actually plan to do with it, we couldn't possibly say.  And SO is a place to ask for specific questions about how to solve specific problems.  If you *have* no problem, and your code works, then that's not on topic here.  If you just want a general code review, rather than to ask a specific question, that's not on topic on SO.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll move this over to CodeReview.